# Boost not recognizing itself as a class

Tags: visual-c++, boost

boost is giving me the "error C2653 'boost': is not a class or namespace name" im trying to use the last_write_time() function from boost filesystem my usage is boost::filesystem::last_write_time(boost::filesystem::path("C:\file.txt"));
im using namespace std and the command is being ran in the main function 
im also getting the error identifier not found but im pretty sure thats from it not detecting the class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include "pch.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Windows.h"
#include "psapi.h"
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <fileapi.h>
```

Comment: Hi, can you show the actual code you are trying to compile ?

Comment: the code im trying to compile is: time_t tim = boost::filesystem::last_write_time(boost::filesystem::path("C:\file.txt"));

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `pch.h` is the precompiled header, `#include "pch.h"` should be the first non-comment line in the source file. The compiler ignores everything above it.

Comment: I have precompiled headers turned off for boost if I try to use them boost wont work

Comment: Humor me for a moment. Do you still have these errors if you move `#include "pch.h"` to the top, so it's the first line?

Comment: I get an earlier error where visual c++ wont open the filesystem lib "fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-1_62.lib'"